# When to use the pseudo-median rather than median?

Tags: descriptive-statistics, median

I know the definition of both median and pseudo-median (median of Walsh averages - of all possible pairs of data). I know, that they both agree in case of symmetric data. I know the pseudo-median is used within the Mann-Whitney (unpaired) and the Wilocoxon paired tests, also their generalizations like Kruskal-Wallis.

But my question is - without any reference to external procedures, where it may be used at its core - is there any application for the pseudomedian itself to descbribe data the same way we call median(x), mean(x)? Just as a descriptive statistics?

Median, being just a quantile, is defined for any distribution, for which we can find the empirical CDF or approximate it with some "typical" distribution's CDF. We know that it splits the (ordered) data set by half, that it's equal to geometric mean in the log-normal distribution or is equal to 50%-trimmed mean.

OK, what are some important and intuitive properties of the pseudomedian? Is this nothing but a supportive construct for introducing tests based on stochastic equivalence, like the Mann-Whitney? Sure, we need the pseudomedian here, because this test, in general, is not about equality of medians (or median of differences for the paired case), but is there something beyond?

Why is the pseudomedian so very rare outside biological science?

Comment: I wouldn’t expect much more than the obvious but boring answer: It’s useful in tests but not otherwise very useful as a descriptive statistic.

Comment: Thank you. Well, it's a good measure to handle so overall term as "equality of distributions" based on the stochastic equivalence. I was just curious if it can be "detached" and do something more "beyond" that. But if not - not a problem, curiosity satisfied, thank you for your answer!

Comment: It tends to be fairly efficient as an estimator of center with smooth symmetric distributions that have normal-looking middles and exponential tails.